# Bizarre issue with echo

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem echoing an error message.

This snippet works:

```
    <p id="email-error" class="text-danger"><?php $first = 'The email must be a valid email address.'; echo $first; ?></p>
```

In the following snippet, the value of $first is set elsewhere. The logged value is correct (and identical to the hardcoded message in the first example), but nothing gets echoed:

```
    <p id="email-error" class="text-danger"><?php Log::info('Value of first: '.$first); echo $first; ?></p>
```

This is a Laravel Blade template. It doesn't matter whether I use the form above or Blade's double curly braces with no echo call.

I have also verified that the value of $first is still correctly set after the echo call.

It also doesn't change the behavior if I remove the Log statement.

I've validated that I'm not getting a double page load.

I'm completely stumped. Ideas?

Comment: You should use `{{ $var }}` and stop assigning values to things inside views. It's really bad practice...

Comment: @Amelia Obviously. I started with {{ $errors->first() }} . I assigned the variable earlier so I could check it. I removed the curly braces to eliminate the possibility that Blade syntax might be an issue. As I said, that makes no difference at all to the outcome, so it's kind of an irrelevant point.

Comment: What is your php file name exactly (are you using .blade.php in name)? Do you get an error, or `{{ $var }}` just prints nothing, but you get outer HTML?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Yes, it's a .blade.php name. There are no errors (debug enabled). All the HTML prints out fine except the <p> element is empty in the second case. I've also eliminated any possibility of caching effects.

Comment: try a vary_dump (or laravel's dd() ), it's likely the variable is just empty. A standard echo or print to the page will possibly not show the value of an empty variable ('', null, false, etc).

Comment: @Emn1ty You're onto something. Log says it's not empty, but var_dump says it is. I didn't think Log was deferred (since that would kind of defeat much of the purpose of it). Maybe I need to do a deep dive into execution order? Uggh.

Comment: Use handlebars like so {{ $var }}